# Opening a Blank Page when trying to open a Blob object from database

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring

```
  Opening a Blank Page when trying to open a Blob object from database
```

Below is the code that I used for opening the BLOB object which is persisted in the DB

```
public void streamData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, IOException {

    if (rs . getString("content_type") . equals("text/html")) {
        output . setContentType("text/plain");
    } else {
        output . setContentType(rs . getString("content_type"));
    }
    if (rs . getString("content_type") . equals("application/octet-stream")) {
        String filename = rs . getString("filename");
        // prompt to open or save attachment
        output . setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    } else if (rs . getString("content_type") . equals("text/html")) {
        output . setContentType("text/plain");
    } else {
        output . setContentType(rs . getString("content_type"));
    }
    InputStream is = lobHandler . getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, "content");
    if (is != null) {
        FileCopyUtils . copy(is, output . getOutputStream());
    }
}
```

If i add any new attachment , I am able to view the attached document ,but I am getting blank page for the BLOB objects which i copied from another server.

I am using MySql Server.

I humbly request to please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: How are you invoking this method? I.E from the JSP / JSF how are you calling this method.

Comment: I am invoking this method Using Spring MVC

Comment: You you have a `target` set  like `target='_blank'` on the link